# Difference in magnitude of two medians

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, median

Once one is confident that two groups have different medians, how can one settle on a reliable magnitude to report for the difference? Here's an example to make my question clearer:

A company wants to maximize the amount of time a user stays on its website. Most users leave right away, but there is a long tail of users who stay for a very long time. The company collects hundreds of thousands of sample times. A consultant designs and sets up a differently formatted website, which is sometimes randomly shown, resulting in a separate data set of times. The consultant uses statistical methods to verify that the two sites have different medians, and the site he designed has a higher median (let's say the medians are 10 seconds and 20 seconds). Is there a way for him to say to the company that he is 95% confident he can lift the median by x to y seconds (or x% to y%)? Or can he only correctly say that his site was shown to have a different median than the first and it was observed to be 100% higher in this case?